# Git undo last commit

Tags: git

I merged the wrong way between two branches. I then ran the following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

I am now back at the previous commit (which is where I want to be). Was that the correct thing to do?

The bad commit is still in the repository, is that okay or should I do something else to remove it from the repository?

I have not pushed or committed anything else yet.

Comment: For posterity, you might want to correct your command. It was `git reset …`, not `git commit …`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's the right thing to do.

You can do a `git gc` to garbage collect disconnected commits, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Well, it'll take 90 days before `git gc` removes that commit. Commits reachable from the reflog count as reachable, and the reflog takes 90 days to expire (by default). But the gist of the answer is right: git's looking out for you, trying not to permanently delete anything, just in case.

Comment: @Jefromi: Nailed it. I try not to suggest `gc` to people, because it's about the only non-reversible operation in git.

Comment: You could also do git reset --soft HEAD^

Answer (score 1):

Using the `^` with `HEAD^` didn't work for me. Instead I had to use the reference from: http://gitref.org/basic/#commit

> git reset --soft HEAD~

(`git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)`)

(Note: if you are using `zsh` (as I do) you can also escape the `^` character instead of alternate command I gave above)

Comment: Are you using zsh? If you are you need to escape the ^

Comment: Thanks :D I am. what a weird caveat

Answer (score 0):

mmmm...
[git revert](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) may be is what you need

Also [this](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) article could help you.

Comment: Thanks, however I did not want to generate a reverse commit.